# Actionscript 3 to LLVM IR?

Tags: actionscript-3, llvm

So, I've got a code obfuscater originally built to obfuscate C/C++ code, but that I've now converted to obfuscate anything that can compile down to LLVM IR. Now I'm looking to obfuscate actionscript 3 source but, from what I can tell, there is no open-source LLVM frontend for actionscript. It looks like Adobe's built an internal LLVM front end in order to compile actionscript for ARM (for use with iOS devices), but it looks like it's proprietary. Can anyone think of any other potential pipeline from projects they may have heard about (i.e. actionscript-> C++ -> LLVM via clang)? I've been searching but can't find anything that's both reliable and open-source. Failing that, has anyone tried to rip the LLVM libraries out of the flash iOS packager so I can reduce the workload required to build my own LLVM frontend for actionscript?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/), [Haxe](http://haxe.org/), and [CrossBridge](https://github.com/crossbridge-community/crossbridge).